# Flow of data from HTTPS to HTTP server

Tags: php, http, ssl, https, parse-platform

Is sending a username/password combination from a SSL protected server (i.e. Parse.com) to my own, HTTP server secure? Will the data sent be vulnerable?

If it is vulnerable, is it possible to encrypt the data in the SSL server, and send it to the HTTP server to be decrypted? I'd like to make the handoff as fast as possible, since I have multiple connections to be made: A mobile user sends login info to Parse.com (HTTPS encrypted) to be stored. Parse then tells my HTTP server to take the login info and do stuff with it. As far as I'm aware, Parse can't do PHP stuff, right?

If you have an idea for a better flow, please tell me. The reason I'm not doing the database stuff from Parse is because I need the SSL connection and I need access to Push Notifications.

Comment: why not buy an ssl certificate, they are not expensive

Comment: SSL connects your Browser securely to the Server. You have to have the certificate to decrypt.

Comment: Since Parse has Push notifications already, why not just utilize its SSL at the same time?

Comment: @Dagon: *"why not buy an ssl certificate, they are not expensive"* - you can get free ones from [StartCom](http://www.startssl.com/) and [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org/). They are Class 1, which means domain validation and no wildcards.

Comment: *StartCom* nope never, no way.

Comment: Any use of Parse via the SDKs provided only use HTTPS and are thus secure, the only way to expose information in a non-secure way is if you deliberately do something like open a HTTP request from within some Cloud Code and send data that way. Perhaps provide some code for what you're doing so we have more context here?

Comment: I don't actually have code yet, but what I was thinking of doing was getting login info from the app, sending the data to Parse to be stored, and (from the app) call a cloud code/PHP function that just tells my PHP server that a new user has been registered (maybe by sending the index?). The PHP server would then access this new data in Parse and do stuff with it. Maybe you could help me with what kind of data should the app give to the PHP server to tell it that new data has been entered? If the app grows, multiple users may have registered at the same time, so sending indices may not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is sending a username/password combination from a SSL protected server (i.e. Parse.com) to my own, HTTP server secure? Will the data sent be vulnerable?

Yes, if anything is sent over the wire unencrypted, it can be snooped.

If all of this happened in a data center that you control it would generally require physical access to the data center to snoop (or a well-planted virus).  It sounds like this is happening over the Internet though, which provides multiple points where your unencrypted credentials could be intercepted.

> If it is vulnerable, is it possible to encrypt the data in the SSL server, and send it to the HTTP server to be decrypted?

If the HTTPS server calls your HTTP server, the data will not be encrypted by HTTPS.  You would need some external means of encryption.

If you make a call to Parse.com's HTTPS server, that call is encrypted.

I agree with @Dagon, pick up a low-cost SSL certificate.

Comment: It's a small project. If I were to poke my HTTP server from Parse.com to read Parse's data, would that data be encrypted/secure?

Comment: If *you* call *parse.com*, that would be encrypted.  If they call you, it would not be encrypted.

Comment: Sounds good. If I'm just sending a boolean or something to tell my own server to look at Parse, I'm right in that it wouldn't need to be encrypted, correct?

Comment: Correct.  As long as there is no sensitive information (including session IDs) you should be fine.